# Youtube video is not looping

Tags: loops, video, youtube

I am using youtube embed code to show a video. But the loop option is not working.

How can I make that work?

here is the code I am using

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ejoIgFsmqxA?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&loop=1"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [Youtube docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop) you will see that the loop parameter has some limitations:

> Note: This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player. Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video, set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL [...]

So, it seems that it could work (not tested) if you add `&playlist=ejoIgFsmqxA` at the end of the iframe src like this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ejoIgFsmqxA?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&loop=1&playlist=ejoIgFsmqxA"></iframe>
```